# What does the git error: "some refs could not be read" mean, and how do I fix it?

Tags: git

I am getting this git error in my IDE:
*"error: some refs could not be read"*

I've been searching the internet, but I can't find it documented anywhere.

- How can I reproduce it on the command line?
- How do I fix it?

*EDIT:*

```
$ git show-ref

112-hash-ed refs/heads/7_1
/* more of these */
a4b-hash-cc refs/heads/master
e5-hash-b1 refs/remotes/origin/4_6
/* many more of these */
a4-hash-dc refs/remotes/origin/master
97-hash-62 refs/tags/4.3.7
/* more of these */
c6-hash-75 refs/tags/show
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using? When does the error occur? Can you add the output of `git show-ref` to your question?

Comment: @Cupcake I'm using IntelliJ and the error occurs when I try to view the details of a commit. In the "Contained in branches" field I see the text: `Can not load branches due to error: error: branch 'origin/HEAD' does not point at a commit error: some refs could not be read error: branch 'origin/HEAD' does not point at a commit error: some refs could not be read`

Comment: @trojanfoe That's why I'm starting with what appears like the root cause, and which seems unrelated to Idea.

Comment: I'll attempt to answer the other question.

Comment: You did ask better already few hours ago, didn't you?